# GWT add widget UIBundle style at runtime

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, uibinder

In a GWT application i am declaring the .css styles inside the UiBinder (ui.xml)

For example:

```
<ui:Style>
    .input {
        background:green;
    }
</ui:Style>
```

And if i declare a Widget inside the UiBinder i reference the Style i was like below:

```
<g:Button styleName="{Style.input}"/>
```

which is fine.

My problem is that i want to apply that style in a Widget that i add at run time. For example a text box:

```
TextBox box = new TextBox();
box.setStyleName("input");
```

I have tried all the possible compinatations (e.g. "input", "{Style.input}"), but without any luck. I know that GWT compiles the styles inside a UiBinder file so the Widgets end up with something like "class="GLIX78"".

Is there any way i can achieve adding a style which is declared at UiBinder in a Widget at runtime?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the style, which you have declared in UiBinder. But you need to take some additional steps. Look at this example:

UiBinder

```
  <!-- (1) declare your style , remember to set the type attribute correctly - you should place your package.WidgetName.StyleName in there -->
 <ui:style type='z.client.TEstWidget.MyStyle'>
    .blackBG {
        background-color: black;
    }

    .grayBG {
        background-color: gray;
    }
  </ui:style>


  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:Label ui:field="myLabel" styleName="{style.grayBG}">test</g:Label>
    <g:Button ui:field="myButton">change style</g:Button>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
```

Widget code

```
public class TEstWidget extends Composite {

    private static TEstUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(TEstUiBinder.class);

    interface TEstUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, TEstWidget> {
    }

    // declare the style (2)
    interface MyStyle extends CssResource {

        String blackBG();

        String grayBG();
    }

    // (3) here you make reference to the style declared in uibinder
    @UiField
    MyStyle style;

    @UiField
    Button myButton;

    @UiField
    Label myLabel;

    public TEstWidget() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }


    @UiHandler("myButton")
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
        // change the background of the label
        // (4) this is how you can use your style
        myLabel.removeStyleName( style.grayBG());
        myLabel.addStyleName(style.blackBG());
    }
}
```